# How to Double integrate a function Separately?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

I have function f[x,y] where i need to integrate f[x,y] with x first and then later i need to integrate that f[x,y]dx with y.
I will be getting f[x,y]dx from another notebook after using Get["ffile"] function.
 Is there a way to Integrate this function separately. I tried Direct double integration it worked properly.I'm able to get plot but unable to integrate separately .

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[
Context[], "*"]]]
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
CleanSlate[]; 
ClearInOut[];  

f[x_, (y_)?NumericQ] := 
   Sin[x*y]*Cos[x + y];  

g[y_] := NIntegrate[f[x, y], 
   {x, 0, Pi}]  

avggy = NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 0, Pi}]  

Plot[g[y], {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

I'm getting this error
 "The integrand f[x,y] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all \ sampling points in the region with boundaries".
 Is there a way to Integrate this? any suggests are highly appreciated.
Thanking you.

I'm Sorry for editing after getting response to above doubt.

This is what i'm trying to do

```
f123[(y_)?NumericQ, 
   (z_)?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Sin[x*y]*Cos[x + y] + z, 
   {x, 0, Pi}]  

Save["ffucntion", 
  testFfunction]
```

I will call this function from another notebook

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[
Context[], "*"]]]
Needs[
   "Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
CleanSlate[]; 
ClearInOut[];  

Get["ffucntion"]; 
g[(y_)?NumericQ] := 
  f123[y, y^2]  

avgg = NIntegrate[g[y], 
   {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

I'm getting this error ."The integrand g[y] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all \
sampling points in the region with boundaries"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

Looking at the code from your edit, I think the problem is that you are saving the wrong function (`testFfunction` instead of `f123`). Try:

```
Save["ffucntion", f123]
```

in your first notebook. And then run

```
Get["ffucntion"]; 
g[(y_)?NumericQ] := f123[y, y^2]  

avgg = NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

in your other notebook. It seems to work for me without any errors and yields 257.566.

**Original:**

Your `?NumericQ` is in the wrong spot.

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x*y]*Cos[x + y];

g[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}]

avggy = NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 0, Pi}]

Plot[g[y], {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image: Plot of integrated function.]

We want to prevent `NIntegrate` from doing any symbolic manipulation, so we check to make sure that `g[y]` only evaluates once y has taken on a numeric value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I'm extremely sorry for asking again. I edited my code . Would you help me out. Thanking you.

Comment: @GummalaNavneeth I've edited my answer. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help